# Objective-C syntax question

Tags: objective-c, syntax

is there in objective-c something similar to ruby's:

```
foobar = foo || bar
```

while foo is nil and bar is 1... so foobar will become 1 or something else if foo wouldn't be nil :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C's ternary conditional operator:

```
foobar = foo != nil ? foo : bar;
```

In general, it takes the form

```
<var> = <condition to test> ? <true value> : <false value>;
```

---

As Wevah noted, if you enable GNU C99 extensions (`-std=gnu99`) you can also do

```
foobar = foo ?: bar
```

Comment: If you've got GCC extensions enabled (e.g., via std=gnu99), you can also do: foobar = foo ?: bar;

Comment: @Wevah: post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @bresc: It's really just expansing on mipadi's answer, though…